# How to add a custom word list to inkrecognizer in uwp?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, inkcanvas, handwriting-recognition

I have developped a uwp app that has a custom user control allowing handwriting recognition of the user input with a stylus into a textbox.

It works fine for common words, however my users often use technical terms and acronyms that are not always recognised or not recognised at all because they are not featured in the language I have set as the default recognizer for my InkRecognizer.

Here is how I set the default Inkrecognizer :

```
InkRecognizerContainer inkRecognizerContainer = new InkRecognizerContainer();

foreach (InkRecognizer reco in inkRecognizerContainer.GetRecognizers())
{
    if (recognizerName == "Reconnaissance d'écriture Microsoft - Français")
    {
        inkRecognizerContainer.SetDefaultRecognizer(reco);
        break;
    }
}
```

And how I get my recognition results :

```
IReadOnlyList<InkRecognitionResult> recognitionResults = new List<InkRecognitionResult>();
recognitionResults = await inkRecognizerContainer.RecognizeAsync(myInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer, InkRecognitionTarget.All);
foreach (var r in recognitionResults)
{
    string result = r.GetTextCandidates()[0];
    myTextBox.Text += " "+result;
}
```

The expected results are generally not contained in the other textcandidates either.

I have read through the msdn documentation of Windows.UI.Input.Inking but haven't found anything useful on this particular topic.
Same goes for the Channel9 videos existing around handwriting recognition and the results that my google-fu have been able to conjure up.
Ideally, I'm looking for something similar to the [WordList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms829122.aspx) that existed in Windows.Inking

Is there a way to programatically add a wordlist to the pool of words of an Inkrecognizer or create a custom dictionary for handwriting recognition in a uwp app ?

Comment: I am looking for this solution too, especially in the context Chinese character recognition. The speech recognition API allows for a custom dictionary or constraints, but have not found anything similar for handwriting input yet.

Comment: For anyone who wants this, please vote up this feature request on Windows Developer feedback: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/33624895-inking-custom-word-list